# why DSR is not working in FANET in NS2 using z=10.0

Tags: tcl, ns2, adhoc, ns-3, nam

I am trying to implement Fanet for 24 nodes where source will be sending packets to destination node. Here Source and destination nodes will be mobile and other nodes will be stationary and act as neighbouring nodes. nodes will be connected with TCP and CBR.

here is the following code of DSR implementation in TCL

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type 
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model 
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type 
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type 
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type 
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type 
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model 
set val(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq 
set val(nn)             24                          ;# number of mobilenodes 
set val(rp)             DSR                       ;# routing protocol 
set val(x)              500                ;# X dimension of topography 
set val(y)              400                ;# Y dimension of topography   
set val(stop)       150            ;# time of simulation end 



set ns_       [new Simulator]

set tracefd       [open dsr.tr w] 
set namtrace      [open dsr.nam w] 

$ns_ trace-all $tracefd 
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y) 


set topo [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
create-god $val(nn)


# configure the nodes 
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
                   -llType $val(ll) \
                   -macType $val(mac) \
                   -ifqType $val(ifq) \
                   -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
                   -antType $val(ant) \
                   -propType $val(prop) \
                   -phyType $val(netif) \
                   -channelType $val(chan) \
                   -topoInstance $topo \
                   -agentTrace ON \
                   -routerTrace ON \
                   -macTrace OFF \
                   -movementTrace ON
                   
                   
###  Creating The WIRELESS NODES
                  
      set Server1 [$ns_ node]
      set Server2 [$ns_ node]
      
    for {set i 2} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
    set n($i) [$ns_ node]
    $n($i) set X_ [ expr 10+round(rand()*150) ]
    $n($i) set Y_ [ expr 10+round(rand()*240) ]
    $n($i) set Z_ 0.0
    $ns_ at 0.0 "$n($i) label node$i"
    }
    
      
      
###  Setting The Initial Positions of Nodes

      $Server1 set X_ 5.0
      $Server1 set Y_ 5.0
      $Server1 set Z_ 0.0
      
      $Server2 set X_ 490.0
      $Server2 set Y_ 285.0
      $Server2 set Z_ 0.0
      
## Giving Mobility to Nodes
$ns_ at 10.0 " $Server1 setdest 250.0 250.0 3.0"
$ns_ at 15.0 " $Server2 setdest 45.0 280.0 5.0"
$ns_ at 110.0 "$Server1 setdest 480.0 300.0 5.0" 



      
## Setting The Node Size
                              
      $ns_ initial_node_pos $Server1 30
      $ns_ initial_node_pos $Server2 30
      
      

      #### Setting The Labels For Nodes
      
      $ns_ at 0.0 "$Server1 label Server1"
      $ns_ at 0.0 "$Server2 label Server2"
      
      

      
# Set a TCP connection between server 1 and server 2
set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Reno]
$tcp set class_ 2
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
#set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$ns_ attach-agent $Server1 $tcp 
$ns_ attach-agent $Server2 $sink 
$ns_ connect $tcp $sink
set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr attach-agent $tcp
$cbr set packetSize_ 1000    
$cbr set interopt_ .07
$ns_ at 10.0 "$cbr start"

# Define node initial position in nam 
for {set i 2} {$i <$val(nn)} { incr i } { 
# 30 defines the node size for nam 
$ns_ initial_node_pos $n($i) 30 
} 
 
# Telling nodes when the simulation ends 
for {set i 2} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } { 
    $ns_ at $val(stop) "$n($i) reset"; 
}

      
# ending nam and the simulation  
$ns_ at $val(stop) "$ns_ nam-end-wireless $val(stop)" 
$ns_ at $val(stop) "stop" 
$ns_ at 150.01 "puts \"end simulation\" ; $ns_ halt" 
proc stop {} { 
    global ns_ tracefd namtrace 
    $ns_ flush-trace 
    close $tracefd 
    close $namtrace 
    #Execute nam on the trace file 
    exec nam dsr.nam & 
    exit 0 
} 
puts "Starting Simulation........"
$ns_ run
```

When i try to make z=10.0, in the nam file simulation, node and destination are connecting directly. they are not using neighbouring nodes. As per definition DSR would work via neighbour node hops if it is nearby.

i want to implement DSR in FANET where z=10.0 is necessary. Why it is happening? is DSR doesn't work with FANET or z=10.0?

please let me know where i am doing wrong or my concept of implementation is wrong?

Comment: Not really a "Fanet"  simulation : Missing like `set val(z) 500` and the " **cube** line `$topo load_cube $val(x) $val(y) $val(z) 1`, see sketcy__Template.txt https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CcOTsnaPXiMBt7xS8Iv2vkhfJZTEf5gq?usp=sharing **and** geo3D-ex-5.tar.xz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0FIaCMV6d5PSEeDUPgmiFlFC8KMbZvh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Besides @KnudLarsen's comment, for DSR I found some notes of folks mentioning that on the `set val(ifq)` you should use `CMUPriQueue` instead of the current one you are using (`Queue/DropTail/PriQueue`).

Comment: @KnudLarsen, load_cube $val(x) $val(y) $val(z) 1 : this line is throwing me an error (_o10 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within

"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o10" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$topo load_cube $val(x) $val(y) $val(z) 1"
    (file "dsr1.tcl" line 29)... should i have to install geo patch?

Comment: @FilipeFreire, CMUPriQueue had worked to omit the segmentation warning perhaps :)

Comment: rony01 : Please run the examples `z10__Geo-3D__rony01.tcl` , `Nakagami-z10__Geo-3D__rony01.tcl` . If any issues, maybe build a new ns-2.35+geo+ns2||3D → see `HOWTO-ns2_geo3D` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CcOTsnaPXiMBt7xS8Iv2vkhfJZTEf5gq?usp=drive_link

Comment: @KnudLarsen, well i tried both files and both are giving me the same error: "$topo load_cube $val(x) $val(y) $val(z) 1"
    (file "geo3d.tcl" line 31). but when i use Nakagami and $topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y) and $n($i) set X_ [ expr 100+round(rand()*450) ] after setting all the z to 10.0 .server1 is connecting with server2 via node 4 or random node which means that they are having one hop to communicate. but load_cube is not working for me. FYI this is my second work within 2 weeks with ns2. i am very new to ubuntu also.... what might be the problem of having error with load_cube?

Comment: `cube` is added to `ns-2.35/mobile/topography.cc` with `geo+ns2-3D_ns235.patch-3` , lines 2542, 3309.. 3319, 3350. The patch is a text file : Is readable, also with grep : `$ grep -n cube geo+ns2-3D_ns235.patch-3`